# Why am I getting a web.config error about missing connection name now?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I'm getting an error for my web.config in my ASP.NET MVC3 Razor project where I've been working on a new branch:

```
The connection name 'ApplicationServices' was not found in the 
applications configuration or the connection string is empty.
```

With this specific error:

```
Line 34:       <providers>
Line 35:         <clear/>
Line 36:         <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
applicationName="/"/>
Line 37:       </providers>
Line 38:     </membership>
```

In `<connectionStrings>` section of the web.config, there isn't an entry for `ApplicationServices`.  However, I've compared my web.config against previous versions that were working and this part of the webconfig hasn't changed at all.  My trunk has this same line in it also.

I've looked at the `<connectionStrings>` section and nothing has changed there either between this branch and the working trunk. So this means that a connection name wasn't removed to trigger this error.

I'm wondering if there is something else I've changed in the project that is now surfacing an error for this line. But I have no idea what it might be. Any ideas?

Comment: You must have connection string for AspNetSqlMembershipProvider, so it knows where to save data. By default it saves it to local App_Data directory using sql express or compact edition depending on the version.

Comment: Are you using forms authentication for the site?

Comment: @dbaseman There is this section in the web.config: `<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"/></authentication>` but I'm not using any authentication in this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what changed between your last revision and the current one.  However, if you're not using forms authentication, then there's no need for this "membership" section; it should be safe to remove it.  And that should fix the error you're seeing.  (Whether there will be other errors in its place is yet to be seen ...)

Comment: no idea why those sections were causing problems now. But removing them solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This section maybe hasn't changed, **but** the `<connectionStrings>` section probably has - there used to be a "ApplicationServices" connection string there.

Comment: The `<connectionStrings>` section hasn't changed either. I just double checked.

Answer (score 0):

Is your web site running while nested within another web site?  If the web.config truly hasn't changed, then perhaps it was working before because it was inheriting the connection string from the parent site.

Comment: It's the same single solution with 2 projects within it, call them `Foo` and 'Bar'.  `Foo` is the root website (http://company.com) and `Bar` is a subsite (http://company.com/sub/).   Connection string hasn't changed in either project, I just re-verified against the trunk.